# How does the Tesseract library calculate the confidence level of each box?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am currently using **pytesseract** **image_to_data** to compute the average confidence level of the strings. However, I am interested to know the theory behind it. What kind of algorithm is involved in such computation? Could anyone enlighten me?